# android - how to play audio and display textview on click a button

Tags: java, android, audio

I am a beginner. So far I have created an app that counts. I created a button which displays the text but it should also play the whistle sound.

I displayed my java code below.

```
/**
 * Displays the winning team.
 */


public void displayForWinner(String score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
```

Comment: Please Google like below and google will show you results .Then select a link and read and try ,First 1.how to play a sound clip on a button click android  2.How to set text to a textView android. Google is a search engine and it gives you better search results and its very fast it wont take that much time like you type the question here .Here its link www.google.com/

Comment: Sir... I have tried to Google search as u said... But I wasted my time... I asked question I got the answer...

Comment: well then good luck.Save your time as you can by asking questions from others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play a short sound effect, create an empty `MediaPlayer` object:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
```

Next, assign a `MediaPlayer` to it using your context, and sound (Place your sound file under app/src/main/res/raw/) :

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.whistle_sound);
```

Finally, when you're ready to play your sound, call:

```
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

**-EDIT-**

To make the text change after your sound has completed,  use this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.whistle_sound);
    }
    public void displayForWinner(String score) {
        final String FinalScore = score;
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(FinalScore));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, consider trimming your audio clip to reduce delay.

Comment: replace "MyActivity" with the name of your activity. :)

Comment: This works thank you sir.... But the text displays first and the whistle later... I need the whistle to play first and the text  should be displayed with some time delay of 1 or 2 sec... Can u help me?

Comment: `mMediaPlayer.start();
 mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {` Cannot resolve the symbol mMediaPlayer for both the lines

Comment: Can you post your code? (starting with "public void displayForWinner")

Comment: `public void displayForWinner(String score) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Dont forget to add this to your "onCreate" method: `mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.whistle_sound);`

Comment: ...and put `MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;` above your "onCreate" method

Comment: `scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));` the score shows an error "needs to be declared final"

Comment: Sorry... error cleared... and it works fine... I had a reset button too to reset the score and to clear the displayforwinner string. now when i press the reset button it plays the whistle sound.I don't need whistle sound for my reset button. code for my reset button displayes below...                                                                   public void reset(View v) {
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA = 0);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB = 0);
        displayForWinner(reset);
    }

Comment: Use an if statement to check the input (When you click reset, the input is "Reset") then decide if you need to make the sound or not. Also, I'd recommend the Android course on Treehouse: [link](http://referrals.trhou.se/theprogrammingbird) That is where I started.

Comment: Problem solved... I created another method with same textview and called it in the reset method. And really Thank You :) :) :)... I am studing my online course in udacity...